# Regular expression in Jmeter with digit

Tags: regex, jmeter

how can i get digit 2958??

$.nav.urlForward(APPLICATION_BASE_URL + "/cce/cashActivity/load.go?cashActivity.id=" + 2958 + "&fromCashActivity=Y");

Comment: can you edit your question to add the http response and Regex extractor

Answer (score 0):

JMeter uses [Perl5-style regular expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) so single digit can be matched as `\d`. Multiple digits (as in your case) can be matched as `\d+`

So if `$.nav.urlForward(APPLICATION_BASE_URL + "/cce/cashActivity/load.go?cashActivity.id=" + 2958 + "&fromCashActivity=Y");` is the **whole** response you can extract 2958 as simple as `(\d+)`

[image: Regex digits]

If you need to match the string and extract 2958 from it, make sure you escape the following characters with a backslash:

```
^$*+?()[{\|
```

So the regular expression becomes:

```
\$.nav.urlForward\(APPLICATION_BASE_URL \+ "/cce/cashActivity/load.go\?cashActivity.id=" \+ (\d+) \+ "&fromCashActivity=Y"\);
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Regex Escape]

See [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) With JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter) article for more details on correlating dynamic values using regular expressions.

Comment: as there the multiple number in the http response that is why your answer will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The following regular expression help me to find out exact answer that I wanted.

> ```
>  id=" [+ ](.+?)[ +] "&fromCashActivity=Y
> ```

From above expression I am able to find out 2958 from my string.